# Why can't I mix C++ universal references with standard reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand C++11's universal references, and wrote the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

template <typename L, typename R>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
static void Run(L&& lhs, const R& rhs) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  lhs += rhs;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

static void Run2(int&& lhs, const int& rhs) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  lhs += rhs;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  int a = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  int b = 3;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Run(a, b);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  printf("%d\n", a);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  // This does not compile.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Run2(a, b);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  printf("%d\n", a);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Note that `Run()` works, but the line calling `Run2()` will fail to compile.  I can't really figure out why.  The error I get is `no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for 1st argument`.

I'm sure the compiler is right, but I can't figure out under why.  It seems to be `Run()` and `Run2()` are doing the same things right?

Btw, changing `Run2()` to be templated with a single parameter also does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Universal references" can only happen in contexts where the type of the reference is deduced, such as in a template type context `T&&`. In this case, T can either be deduced as `int` for an rvalue argument, and so you have `int&&` as the argument type; or as `int&` for your lvalue argument, which would give the type `int& &&` that per reference collapsing rules becomes just `int&`. In your Run2 function, the type is directly `int&&` and so it cannot bind to any lvalue unless you use `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

Rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues.

The special rule for creating forwarding references is that a deduced template parameter `T` may be deduced as `T = U&` when it appears in a function parameter `T&&`, which makes the function parameter type be `U&` (thanks to reference collapsing from `U& &&`). However, the types of the parameters of `Run2` are not deduced, so the first parameter is directly an rvalue reference.

Changing `Run2` to a function template with a single template parameter means that the argument deduction will fail, since there is no consistent set of types that fits both arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a universal reference (as it described in the book of [Scott Meyers Effective Modern C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996)) and the second one is rvalue reference

In order to make it work you need to call it like this:

```
Run2(std::move(a), b);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Run(a,b)`
calls a function where typename L==int& and R==int

so
`static void Run(L&& lhs, const R& hrs)`

is template instantiated as

`static void Run(int & && lhs, const int& hrs)`

or actually because of reference collapsing, it becomes

`static void Run(int& lhs, const int& hrs)`

`Run2` expects an rvalue reference for `lhs` which it can only get from casting or being given an unnamed variable (temporary). In, your case, you could call the function using a cast:

`Run(std::move(a), b)`